# calling javascript prototype method inside jquery bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

**The code has been stripped down for simplicity and to address need:**
*I understand the methods will make no sense. I just want to know what is illegal and how I can use methods together in a fashion the best I can describe below.*

**The problem comes from the** `bindContentOverlay` **method:**

```
this.setContentOverlayHeight is not a function
this.setContentHeight is not a function
```

**Heres something like what im working with:**
*Any pointers on OOP using this type of style are also more than welcome.*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var p = new Properties();
    p.bindContentOverlay();
});

var Properties = function()
{
    this.initialize();
}

Properties.prototype.initialize = function()
{
    this.menu = {"#power" : null,"#services" : "#services_menu","#cashback" : null,"#schedule" : "#schedule_menu"};
    this.a = 22;
    this.b = 33;
}

Properties.prototype.getHeights = function()
{
    this.initialize();
    this.q = this.a;
    this.w = this.b;
}

Properties.prototype.setContentOverlayHeight = function()
{   
    this.getHeights();
    alert(this.q);
}

Properties.prototype.setContentHeight = function()
{
    this.getHeights();
    alert(this.w);
}


Properties.prototype.bindContentOverlay = function()
{
    for(var i in this.menu)
    {
        (function(x, y) {
             $(x+','+y).hover(
                 function () {
                    console.log(x);
                    this.setContentOverlayHeight();
                 },
                 function () {
                    this.setContentHeight();
                    console.log(y);
                 }
            );
        })(i, this.menu[i]);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `this` in the hover callbacks refers to the element being hovered over, not the current `Properties` object.

The simplest fix is to bind a local reference to `this` at the top of `.bindContentOverlay`:

```
Properties.prototype.bindContentOverlay = function()
{
    var self = this;
    ...
}
```

and then use `self.setContentOverlayHeight()` in the callbacks.

Comment: +1, beat me to it. *Another* `self = this` question lol, how many different ways of this are there

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you define a function in a function, you will likely lose context (the value of `this`).

The problem is how you've written the `bindContentOverlay` method. When those deepest functions execute, `this` isn't what you expect.

The simplest way to prevent this is to save `this` to a local variable and use that instead.

```
Properties.prototype.bindContentOverlay = function()
{
    // Save "this" to local var, and use the var instead for any inner functions.
    var instance = this;

    for(var i in this.menu)
    {
        (function(x, y) {
             $(x+','+y).hover(
                 function () {
                    console.log(x);
                    instance.setContentOverlayHeight();
                 },
                 function () {
                    instance.setContentHeight();
                    console.log(y);
                 }
            );
        })(i, instance.menu[i]);
    }   
}
```